# Why do we sometimes(i often) go to trance while listening to music?

Tags: music

What's the scientific reason behind it?

I can't quite figure out what's around me and it feels so soothing same as the effect of meditation. It feels like an enlightenment.(I feel like I'm connected to a higher deity)

Answer (score 1):

If you take a look at this quick article: [The Neuroscience Of Trance](https://www.nmr.mgh.harvard.edu/news/20150710/neuroscience-trance) or the full published study the article refers to: [Brain Network Reconfiguration and Perceptual Decoupling During an Absorptive State of Consciousness](https://academic.oup.com/cercor/article/26/7/3116/1745376) scientists used fMRI to view what was going on in the brains of shamans as they either entered into a trance or purposefully stopped themselves from doing so while listening to drumming.

One of the things they noted was a dampening of the sensory pathways - there theory being that while the drumming beat was the most prominent external stimulus, it's repetitive and predictable patterns allowed it to be gated out/ignored while its ongoing presence prevented reorienting to the usual random environmental distractions.

I would expect the music your listening to is doing more or less what the drumming does for the shamans.

Comment: thank you. It helped